# Rudin Dedekind Cuts - Define Negative Multiple - Step 8

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am following the construction of the reals using Dedekind Cuts in Rudin's Chapter 1 Appendix.  I would appreciate some review on one of the last steps, Step 8, where he looks at multiplication of the reals.

I am trying to prove property (b), namely that $r^*s^*=(rs)^*$.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3838461) is a good proof for when $r, s>0$.  But what about when $r>0, s<0$?

A few relevant definitions:  (Note that here, so far, $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of Dedekind cuts and $\alpha, \beta$ are cuts.)

1. Fix $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.  Let $-\alpha$ be the set of all $p\in\mathbb{Q}$ with the following property: There exists $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $q>0$ such that $-p-q\notin \alpha$.
2. $\mathbb{R}^+$ is the set of all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha > 0^*$.  ($0^*$ is the set all negative rational numbers.)  Then if $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}^+$, we define $\alpha\beta$ to be the set of all $p$ such that $p\leq rs$ for some choice of $r\in\alpha, s\in\beta$ with $r,s>0$.
3. If $\alpha>0$ and $\beta <0$, $\alpha\beta = -(\alpha(-\beta))$.
4. We associate with each $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ the set $r^*$ which consists of all $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $p<r$.  These $r^*$ are cuts so the above apply.

Here is what I have.  It relies heavily on manipulating definitions so if someone could check this I would be grateful.  Thank you.

First, I show $r^*s^*\subset (rs)^*$:

- Suppose $p\in r^*s^*$.
- By (3), $r^*s^*=(-(r^*(-s)^*))$.
- Thus, by (1), there exists $q>0$ such that $-p-q\notin r^*(-s)^*$.
- By (2), this means that for all $u, v$ with $u\in r^*, v\in (-s)^*$, and $u, v >0$, we have $-p-q>uv$.
- By (4), for all such $u$ and $v$, we know $u<r$ and $v<-s$, so this means $-p-q\geq r(-s)$.
- Since $q>0$, this means $-p> r(-s)$
- This means $p < rs$.
- And by (4), this means $p\in (rs)^*$.

Next I show $(rs)^* \subset r^*s^*$:

- Suppose $p \in (rs)^*$.  Then by (4), $p<rs$.
- Since $r>0, s<0$, we have $rs < 0$, and so $-p>r(-s)$.
- Then there exists $q > 0$ such that $-p-q > r(-s)$.
- By (4), for all $u \in r^*, v\in (-s)^*$, we have $u<r$ and $v<-s$.  Then for all $u \in r^*$ and $v \in (-s)^*$ with $u, v >0$, we have $-p-q>uv$.
- Therefore, by (2), $-p-q\notin r^*(-s)^*$.
- Therefore, by (1), $p \in -(r^*(-s)^*)$.
- By (3), $-(r^*(-s)^*) = r^*s^*$, and so $p \in r^*s^*$.

EDIT: I have noticed one issue with the above.  Twice I wrote that by (3), $-(r^*(-s)^*) = r^*s^*$.  However, a strict application of the definition of the product of a positive and negative cut would be that $r^*s^* = -(r^*(-(s^*)))$ (the difference is subtle, but there).

However, it is not hard to show that for any rational cut, $-(r^*) = (-r)^*$.

Suppose $p\in (-r)^*$.  Then $p\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $p<-r$.  Then there exists $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $q>0$ such that $p+q<-r$.  Then $-p-q>r$, so $-p-q\notin r^*$, and by definition $p\in -(r^*)$.

Next, suppose $p\in -(r^*)$.  Then by definition there exists $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $q>0$ such that $-p-q\notin r^*$, i.e. $-p-q\geq r$.  Then $-p>r$, so $p<-r$ and $p \in (-r)^*$.

Comment: It appears to be fine.

Comment: Thank you for looking @BrianM.Scott!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: "By (2), this means that for all $u, v$ with $u\in r^*, v\in (-s)^*$, and $u, v >0$, we have $-p-q>uv$.
- By (4), for all such $u$ and $v$, we know $u<r$ and $v<-s$, so this means $-p-q\geq r(-s)$. "              <-----How did you determine $-p-q\geq r(-s)$?

Comment: Gary, I’m not sure why it follows from (4) exactly, but this step is equivalent to $(rs)^*\subset r^*s^*$ for $r,s>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my edit and Brian's comment above, it seems like what is in the post body is correct.