# Help With Basic Proof from Rudin PMA Chapter One

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers

From Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Third Edition, page 20, Step 8:

[image]

I want to complete the proof of (b) by proving the following claim.

**Claim**: For $r\in{}\mathbb{Q}^+$ and $s\in{}\mathbb{Q}^-$, $r^*\cdot{}s^*\subset{}(rs)^*$

**Attempt at Proof**: $q\in{}r^*\cdot{}s^*\implies{}q\in{}-[r^*\cdot{}(-s)^*]\implies{}\forall{}r'\forall{}s'(r',s'\in{}\mathbb{Q}^+\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,r'\in{}r^*\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,s'\in{}(-s)^*\implies{}\exists{}a(a\in{}\mathbb{Q}^+\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,-q-a>r's'))$

At this point I am stuck. I need to show $rs>q$ so that $q\in{}(rs)^*$.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971592/rudin-dedekind-cuts-define-negative-multiple-step-8#comment9189930_3971592) covers the question, but I think the proof is wrong at the relevant place and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prove for all rational $r,s$, we have:

(1) $\quad r^* < s^*$ if and only if $r < s$.

(2) $\quad (-r)^* = -(r^*)$

(3) $\quad r,s \ge 0$ implies $r^*s^* = (rs)^*$.

Then, using the definition of multiplication of reals (Rudin's Step 7), the other cases of (3) follow immediately, unless I'm missing something!

I believe the proofs of (1)–(3) are very straightforward, again unless I'm missing something.

(I'm not sure what the etiquette is on this site, but I feel like I should restrict my contribution to getting past the roadblock, not filling in every detail.  Anyway, in the meantime, I have verified that the proofs of (1)–(3) are straightforward.)

Comment: Jeremy is correct. If $r>0,s<0$, then $r^*\cdot{}s^*:=-[r^*\cdot{}(-s)^*]=-[(r\cdot{}-s)^*]=-[(-rs)^*]=(rs)^*$. This makes use of Jeremy's (2) and (3) above. It also means that we don't need to prove inclusion in the manner that I tried to do in the OP. That said, if anyone reads this and can prove the inclusion, I'd love to see it.

Comment: It also uses (1).

Comment: Where? $r^*\cdot{}s^*:=-[r^*\cdot{}-(s^*)]$ (definition) = $-[r^*\cdot{}(-s)^*]$ (2) = $-[(r\cdot{}-s)^*]$ (3) = $-[(-rs)^*]$ (elementary property of rational multiplication)= $(rs)^*$ (2)

Comment: Because you assumed $r > 0$ (for example) but used $r^* > 0^*$.